# ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool - Security Setup Wizard ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to use the security set-up wizard within the ASP.NET Website configuration utility, however I keep getting the error below when clicking next on the 'Select Access Method' page.

> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Method failed with unexpected error code 50. at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext) at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory) at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity..ctor(String fileName, AccessControlSections includeSections) at System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(String path, AccessControlSections includeSections) at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateTemplateAttributes(String source, String destination) at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateFileAttributes(String source, String destination) at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext) at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext) at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext) at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll) at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.SaveConfig(Configuration config) at ASP.security_wizard_wizardauthentication_ascx.UpdateAuth(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I also get this same error if I try to select the Access Method by not using the wizard.

Does anyone know why I am getting this? I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 in Admin mode.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Is the error 50 or 500? If it is 500 I would assume you have a database connection problem -> Check the connection string and determine if the server it is pointing to can be accessed. If it is actually an error code 50 then I have no idea??

Comment: It's not an error 500, I will try and paste the full stack trace later when I'm back at my PC. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have added the full stack trace info now...